# How do I convert a LaTeX PDF to a completely vector file?

Tags: tex-core

So, I have this one math equation I made in Kile. I want it to be then used for printing, so I wanted to export it in AI, SVG or CDR file.

I thought it would be no problem, since, well, LaTeX is all about vectors. Turns out it's not. If I try importing that PDF into Corel Draw, Illustrator or Inkscape, half of the characters are suddenly gone for no reason!!!

So, quickly, how do I convert the PDF with LaTeX with lots of mathematical symbols into purely vector image, so that there are no mistakes/font replacements in the process?

Comment: Characters will not go for no reason it will be a consequence of something in your file, but as you give no clues about the input it is impossible to guess.

Comment: I don't know the other editors, but in Inkscape there are some import settings that could affect this. Maybe read all the options carefully when importing. As David said, it's impossible to know for sure without further information, though.

Comment: Also, I don't really see why you can't just print the PDF directly.

Comment: I think it would be great to have an easy way to do this. I think the "missing chars" problem may be a result of not embedding fonts, or not handling fonts properly at the external tool side. I think a solution would entail rendering the fonts as pure vectorial shapes as intermediate step. Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Pdf2svg?...... .....

Comment: Please provide MWE. In general, you must ensure that Type 1 PostScript fonts are really used (e.g. if you are using Computer Modern font, you must install `cm-super` package), and that all fonts are embedded to PDF.